# using the $filter inside the $expand in the Odata query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to use the filter in the expanded entity using the Odata query like

```
   https://labstest.science.com/DEV/odata/ROOM_REQUEST?$expand=REQ_COLONYROOM($select=Name;$filter=Name eq 'RB05')
```

This works partially. It brings all the ROOM_REQUEST with Null for the REQ_COLONYROOM where Name is not equal to RB05

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://labstest.science.com/DEV/odata/$metadata#ROOM_REQUEST(REQ_COLONYROOM(Name))",
"value": [
    {
        "Id": 18399308,
        "Name": "M1",
        "Barcode": "M1",
        "REQ_COLONYROOM": null
    },
    {
        "Id": 18403071,
        "Name": "M2",
        "Barcode": "M2",
        "REQ_COLONYROOM": {
            "@odata.id": "https://labstest.science.com/odata/COLONY_ROOM('MC19')",
            "Name": "RB05"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": 18403109,
        "Name": "M3",
        "Barcode": "M3",
        "REQ_COLONYROOM": null
    }]}
```

Though M1 and M3 has different Colony than RB05 it returns Null with the odata call

Comment: What are you expecting to be returned here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this:

```
 https://labstest.science.com/DEV/odata/ROOM_REQUEST?$expand=REQ_COLONYROOM&$select=REQ_COLONYROOM/Name&$filter=REQ_COLONYROOM/Name eq 'RB05'
```

I think it would be enough not having SELECT:

```
 https://labstest.science.com/DEV/odata/ROOM_REQUEST?$expand=REQ_COLONYROOM&$filter=REQ_COLONYROOM/Name eq 'RB05'
```

Comment: HI, when i use something similar to above, i get the error response saying:

odata URL: /GlobalRegions?$expand=Countrys&$select=KeyGlobalRegion,GlobalRegion&$filter=Countrys/KeyCountry eq 'US'
Response: 
Error: The parent value for a property access of a property 'KeyCountry' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

In my case, the Countrys 
/Countrys?$select=KeyCountry,CountryName,KeyGlobalRegion&$filter=KeyCountry eq 'US'
gives me:
"value": [
{
  "KeyCountry": "US",
  "CountryName": "United States of America",
  "KeyGlobalRegion": 4
}
]

Comment: Even if use the odata query like:
/GlobalRegions?$expand=Countrys&$select=KeyGlobalRegion,GlobalRegion,Countrys/KeyCountry
I get the Reponse as
Error: Found a path with multiple navigation properties or a bad complex property path in a select clause. Please reword your query such that each level of select or expand only contains either TypeSegments or Properties.

what am i doing wrong here? Its an internal source i am trying to query against.