# How to construct the ODATA query properly with $expand and proper $filter params that would get the SQL equivalent result using joins

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, rest, odata

I will start with the SQL query that works perfectly fine.

Query:

```
select 
univ.UniversityId, univ.UniversityName, c.KeyCountry, c.CountryName, rgn.GlobalRegion, rgn.KeyGlobalRegion
from 
University univ 
left outer join Lookup..Country c on univ.Country = c.KeyCountry
left outer join Lookup..GlobalRegion rgn on c.KeyGlobalRegion = rgn.KeyGlobalRegion
where univ.UnivserityId in
(
   10, 14
)
```

yields me something like:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>UniversityId</th><th>UniversityName</th><th>KeyCountry</th><th>CountryName</th><th>GlobalRegion</th><th>KeyGlobalRegion</th></tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td>Berkeley University</td><td>US</td><td>United States of America</td><td>United States and Canada</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>14</td><td>University of California</td><td>US</td><td>United States of America</td><td>United States and Canada</td><td>4</td></tr>
</table>
```

I thought of showing the table view but ended up doing this html stuff.

Now, when i try to do the same with ODATA query, i am trying to construct something like this:

> */GlobalRegions?$select=KeyGlobalRegion,GlobalRegion&$expand=Countrys($select=KeyCountry,CountryName,KeyGlobalRegion;$expand=Universitys($select=KeyUniversityId,UniversityName,KeyCountry))&$filter=(KeyUniversityId+eq+10)*

I tried putting the $filter with Universitys/KeyUniversityId also but it didn't help. It gives the error:

> *Error: Found a path with multiple navigation properties or a bad complex property path in a select clause. Please reword your query such that each level of select or expand only contains either TypeSegments or Properties.*

Or even if want to filter the GlobalRegions with the specific country like

> *GlobalRegions?$expand=Countrys&$select=KeyGlobalRegion,GlobalRegion,Countrys/KeyCountry*

But if query like this, it works with the country value as child elements:

> *GlobalRegions?$expand=Countrys($select=KeyCountry,CountryName,KeyGlobalRegion)&$select=KeyGlobalRegion,GlobalRegion*

How do I go about doing that odata query for the above SQL I am trying to perform? I have given lots of trials with `$expand=Countrys($select=<column-name>&$filter=<condition>)` and also tried with `<table-name>/<field-name>` also in the select. I explored the [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988592/using-the-filter-inside-the-expand-in-the-odata-query) but that didn't help either.

What can I try next?

Comment: Please note: when adding HTML or XML tags to a question here, they will be rendered as (invalid) HTML unless they are contained in code formatting. I have repaired the presentation of the (missing) code at the end for you.